# ViewModel still displaying old data after dialog dismissed and parent fragment back to view

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-dialogfragment, android-viewmodel

I'm still trying to wrap my head around working with viewmodels and a bit confused now that I also have a dialog and recyclerview items but will try to be as clear as I can here if I can get any help please.

I have a dialog with items that when one of them is selected and closed should return data to my calling fragment so the selected item is displayed under that view.

However, once the item is selected and the dialog dismissed, I don't see the new selected item as the one showing on the UI but still the old item instead. (When the fragment is first started it displays the item that is set as selected on my list. The selected value is hardcoded at first but updated when the item is clicked and I can see the update has taken place when I debug the viewmodel observer inside the onDismiss method for the dialog).

I'm a couple of hours on this and have tried a few different things such as calling the viewmodel inside onResume or onDismiss and changing the viewmodel to be initiated `by by activityViewModels()` as per [this post](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#implement) but none of these have worked so far and I think I'm stuck at the moment. Below my most recent version of the code.

```
class CovidCheckInFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_covid_check_in) {

var navController: NavController? = null
private val model: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
    
    model.userMutableLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Any?> { list ->
        if (list != null)

            (list as Iterable<*>).map {

                if ((it as ModelDialogOption).selected == true) {
                    tvHeader.text = it.title
                }

            }

    })

}

}
```

..

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), RecyclerDialogOptionsItem.AdapterListener {

private val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
private lateinit var adapter: GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>
var selectedPosition = -1

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog_Custom)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    rvOptions.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    adapter = GroupAdapter()
    rvOptions.adapter = adapter


    ivClose.setOnClickListener {

        this.dismiss()
    }


    initViewModel()
}

private fun initViewModel() {

    viewModel.userMutableLiveData.observe(this, Observer { list ->
        for (i in list!!) {
            adapter.add(
                RecyclerDialogOptionsItem(
                    this@MyDialogFragment,
                    i,
                    this@MyDialogFragment
                )
            )
        }

    })

}

override fun onClickItem(position: Int) {

    selectedPosition = position
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    Log.i("clicked", "position: $position")
}

}
```

..

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

private var list: ArrayList<ModelDialogOption>? = null

val userMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ModelDialogOption>?> = MutableLiveData()

init {
    populateList()
    userMutableLiveData.value = list!!
}

private fun populateList() {

    list = ArrayList()

    list!!.add(ModelDialogOption("Prefer not to say", false))
    list!!.add(ModelDialogOption("16-39", false))
    list!!.add(ModelDialogOption("40-59", true))
    list!!.add(ModelDialogOption("60+", false))
}

}
```

..

```
class RecyclerDialogOptionsItem(
private val fragment: MyDialogFragment,
private val modelDialogOption: ModelDialogOption,
private val adapterListener: AdapterListener
) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {

companion object {
    var clickListener: AdapterListener? = null
}

override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {

    viewHolder.apply {

        with(viewHolder.itemView) {

            tvTitle.text = modelDialogOption.title

            clickListener = adapterListener

            if (fragment.selectedPosition == position) {
                ivChecked.visible()
                modelDialogOption.selected = true

            } else {
                ivChecked.invisible()
                modelDialogOption.selected = false
            }

            itemView.setOnClickListener {

                clickListener?.onClickItem(adapterPosition)

            }

        }

    }

}

override fun getLayout() = R.layout.rv_options_item_row

interface AdapterListener {
    fun onClickItem(position: Int)
}

}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is your activity code? In your activity declare the viewModel first. Then CovidCheckInFragment and MyDialogFragment  will get the viewModel ref since you are using activityViewModels(). 
That means CovidCheckInFragment and MyDialogFragment will use the same VM to share and listen the data

Comment: Hi! Sorry, didn't know needed to include code on the activity too? Is there any way to avoid that? I think I'm already confused enough managing these four classes..

Comment: I've updated the post with some simplified version for my activity. Thanks.

Comment: I think I've been able to make it work now replacing the activityViewModels with this ```private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels(
        { requireParentFragment() }
    )``` on both the parent fragment and the dialog one.

Comment: Now just need to figure out how to view this update as soon as the dialog is dismissed because at the moment I'm being required to leave the fragment and come back to it for the changes to take place.

Comment: You need to update or push value to userMutableLiveData in MainViewModel from the Fragment. I cannot see any code except in the init{} of MainViewModel which is updating MutableLiveData. Put a method in MainViewModel to update the MutableLiveData so that OneFragment updates it and Other Fragment got updated

Comment: Okay, I'm reading your message a few times to see if understand it properly to know what is the part I need to figure out how to do now. I'm not sure I know how to do this updating you're referring to but will try to find out. And If I haven't said that yet, thanks a lot for chatting here and helping me with this issue.

Comment: Go to the section "Share data between fragments" in the developer link you have in your question. See carefully that "SharedViewModel" has a function called "select" which is updating the mutableLiveData.

Comment: FYI ...remove initViewModel() from onDismiss method. It does not make sense

Comment: Oh yeah, that's removed already, thanks. It was there just while I was debugging it. :)

Comment: I'm rereading the docs now with the new info on the select method by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221393/discussion-between-francislainy-campos-and-crack-head).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main view model should be like this

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

private var list: ArrayList<ModelDialogOption>? = null

val userMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ModelDialogOption>>()

init {
    populateList()
    userMutableLiveData.value = list!!
}


private fun populateList() {

    list = ArrayList()

    list!!.add(ModelDialogOption("Prefer not to say", false))
    list!!.add(ModelDialogOption("16-39", false))
    list!!.add(ModelDialogOption("40-59", true))
    list!!.add(ModelDialogOption("60+", false))

}

fun updateItem(position:Int){
    val itemToUpdate = list!!.get(position)
    itemToUpdate.selected = !itemToUpdate.selected!!
    list!![position] = itemToUpdate
}

fun flushItems(){
    userMutableLiveData.value = list!!
}
```

}

Then from MyDialogFragment Should be like this.

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), RecyclerDialogOptionsItem.AdapterListener {

private val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

private lateinit var adapter: GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>
var selectedPosition = -1

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog_Custom)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    rvOptions.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    adapter = GroupAdapter()
    rvOptions.adapter = adapter


    ivClose.setOnClickListener {

        this.dismiss()
    }


    initViewModel()
}

override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog)
    viewModel.flushItems()
}

private fun initViewModel() {

    viewModel.userMutableLiveData.observe(this, Observer { list ->
        for (i in list!!) {
            adapter.add(
                RecyclerDialogOptionsItem(
                    this@MyDialogFragment,
                    i,
                    this@MyDialogFragment
                )
            )
        }

    })

}


override fun onClickItem(position: Int) {

    selectedPosition = position
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    viewModel.updateItem(position)
    Log.i("clicked", "position: $position")
}
```

}